# Windows - How to access a tablet's contents via command line

Tags: android, windows-8, tablet

I'll keep my question as short as I can, and as simple. I'm trying to write a windows batch file to backup a specific folder on my android tablet. I've run into the problem of not being able to access (or find) the tablet when it's plugged in using command prompt. So basically what I'm asking:

(1): How does Windows determine the drive or where to go to access the files through the GUI?

(2): Would it be better to use another script to perform this function?

I realize there are better ways of backing up data to a PC but those aren't very viable right now. (No cloud service, no internet access, the tablet can only back up to certain PCs).

Comment: Take a look at this https://github.com/google/adb-sync